# How to obtain the end times of overlapping processes executed in log file?

Tags: python, mysql, regex, python-3.x

First off, I am trying to write a simple py script that can parse or scrape a '.log' file and extract key variables and their values onto a .txt or .csv file. The trouble I'm having is obtaining the end date/time stamp for each process ran by various users. Since these log files are query based, it shows all of the logical and physical SQL processes generated from each user in the database at every second (ms) of the day. So basically, say I run a process at 8:00 AM, my buddy runs one at 8:00 AM too, (or 8:01, 8:02, etc.. doesn't really matter) but say his process ends before mine. Now each start/end time are intertwined and that's not to mention up to a hundred or so other users all throughout the day. Also, each process ran can have 'x' amount of time-stamps in between with various blocks data.

I've managed to capture the start time due to a common pattern I found. The only pattern I know of for the end time is that it has one of the same matching fields as the start time, '[requestid: w+]'. It is a unique identifier. I've been trying to use look-around's in regex but haven't had much luck yet. Is there something better to try or does anyone know any other solution? I'll plug a sample of the log format below. The start time lines always have '#' symbols and the 'SQL Request... hash.' However, if you notice the 'requestid:{}' value, its the same for each one except the last one, since its the start of a new process. The end T/S here is at '09:14:55.22'.(I omitted multiple outputs in between to keep this as short as possible.) The start of a new process happens to be at the very end.

```
[2019-06-12T09:14:54.947-05:00] [OBIS] [TRACE:2] [] [] [ecid: 6ca4862b-14d1-4a7f-8158-5e6cac363144-001477ac,0:1:65:3] [sik: ssi] [tid: 1fbe1700] [messageid: USER-0] [requestid: bf710010] [sessionid: bf710000] [username: kadaniel] ############################################## [[
-------------------- SQL Request, logical request hash:
83bf7e6f
]]
[2019-06-12T09:14:54.995-05:00] [OBIS] [TRACE:2] [] [] [ecid: 6ca4862b-14d1-4a7f-8158-5e6cac363144-001477ac,0:1:65:5] [sik: ssi] [tid: 1fbe1700] [messageid: USER-16] [requestid: bf710010] [sessionid: bf710000] [username: kadaniel] -------------------- Execution plan: [[
]]
[2019-06-12T09:14:55.02-05:00] [OBIS] [TRACE:2] [] [] [ecid: 6ca4862b-14d1-4a7f-8158-5e6cac363144-001477ac,0:1:65:5] [sik: ssi] [tid: 1fbe1700] [messageid: USER-18] [requestid: bf710010] [sessionid: bf710000] [username: kadaniel] -------------------- Sending query to database named Oracle Data Warehouse (id: <<1255810915>>), connection pool named Oracle Data Warehouse Connection Pool, logical request hash 83bf7e6f, physical request hash 336b8897: [[
]]
[2019-06-12T09:14:55.03-05:00] [OBIS] [TRACE:2] [] [] [ecid: 6ca4862b-14d1-4a7f-8158-5e6cac363144-001477ac,0:1:65:5:1] [sik: ssi] [tid: 71d8e700] [messageid: USER-18] [requestid: bf710010] [sessionid: bf710000] [username: kadaniel] -------------------- Sending query to database named Oracle Data Warehouse (id: <<1255810915>> pre query 0), connection pool named Oracle Data Warehouse Connection Pool, logical request hash 83bf7e6f, physical request hash 823a7981: 
]]
[2019-06-12T09:14:55.22-05:00] [OBIS] [TRACE:2] [] [] [ecid: 6ca4862b-14d1-4a7f-8158-5e6cac363144-001477ac,0:1:66] [sik: ssi] [tid: 1fbe1700] [messageid: USER-33] [requestid: bf710010] [sessionid: bf710000] [username: kadaniel] -------------------- Logical Query Summary Stats: Elapsed time 0.077, Total time in BI Server 0.075, Execution time 0.076, Response time 0.077, Compilation time 0.057 (seconds), logical request hash 83bf7e6f
[2019-06-12T09:14:55.343-05:00] [OBIS] [TRACE:2] [] [] [ecid: 6ca4862b-14d1-4a7f-8158-5e6cac363144-001477ac,0:1:189:3] [sik: ssi] [tid: 1fbe1700] [messageid: USER-0] [requestid: bf710020] [sessionid: bf710000] [username: kadaniel] ############################################## [[
-------------------- SQL Request, logical request hash:
8e45939b
```

I just want to gather the End Time into a list or tuple & append it to my other one. However, I ideally want to extract the following fields for each process or record (per 'requestid:{}') in a CSV format: Start Time, username, requestid, End Time, logical request hash. I preferred the re.findall so that way the dates are ordered. If I got any help on this it would mean the world to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to track the first/last timestamps for each request ID:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\[(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}-\d{2}:\d{2})\].*\[requestid: ([a-z0-9]+)\].*\[username: (\w+)\].*$')
process_records = {}
for line in lines:
    m = pattern.match(line)
    if m is not None:
        timestamp, request_id, username = m.groups()
        if request_id not in process_records:
            process_records[request_id] = (timestamp, username, None)
        else:
            process_records[request_id] = process_records[request_id][:2] + (timestamp,)

for request_id, (start, username, end) in process_records.items():
    print("ID:{} Username:{} Start:{} End:{}".format(
        request_id,
        username,
        start,
        end,
    ))
```

Comment: Thank you! The regex is great, resource friendly too. I've never used the CSV module but if I wanted to write to a .bat or .txt file with this parsed info it should be pretty easy right?

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you! But I went through the output to see if all the lines matched correctly and all of it _seemed_ like it did, except for the first End Time record. It was a bit early, recording the 3rd T/S down instead of the 14th. (the End Time) Anyways, I thought this was strange & was wondering if you had any guesses why just that one was off?

Comment: I'm not sure. You'd have to debug (good opportunity to familiarize yourself with `pdb`). Is it possible log records are not emitted in chronological order? Are you sure the `record_id` is being properly picked up with the regex I wrote?

Comment: Everything checks out to me... I messed with the flags, quantifiers, checked token syntax -I'm not sure.

Comment: I figured out the problem. The millisecond quantifier was given {3} instead of {1,3} (or 2,3). Its all successful now!

Answer (score 0):

Write a generator that initializes a dict `job = {}`,
consumes all lines of text,
and takes one of these actions:

1. Stores `job[request_id] = (your, fave, attributes)` upon recognizing a "start" line.
2. Yields `end_time` plus your favorite attributes (like `start_time`) upon recognizing an "end" line.
3. Discards other lines, treating them as noise.

With that in hand you will find it trivial to gather
all matched start / end records by having `list( ... )`
call your generator.
Or use `sorted( ... )`, especially if a column of interest
like `start_time` or `elapsed` appears first.
Or use [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to send output to a file.

Once having `yield`ed feel free to `del` that dict entry,
to conserve memory when reading a long file.